# HTTPConnection request socket.gaierror in python

Tags: python

I encountered an error today while trying to retrieve an XML by sending a 'GET' HTTP request.

```
from httplib import HTTPConnection
import urllib

params = urllib.urlencode({'sK': 'test', 'sXML': 1})
httpCon = HTTPConnection("http://www.podnapisi.net",80)
httpCon.request('GET', '/en/ppodnapisi/search',params)
r1 = httpCon.getresponse()
```

and here is the error i got:

```
.....
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

The XML that I am trying to retrieve [HERE](http://www.podnapisi.net/en/ppodnapisi/search?sK=test&sXML=1)

How can I fix this error ?

Thanks in Advance ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No scheme (`http://`) in the HTTPConnection constructor:

```
httpCon = HTTPConnection("www.podnapisi.net",80)
```

It already knows it's HTTP, it's an HTTPConnection object :)

Comment: Thanks ... it works now, but why do i get an HTML data instead of the XML when printing "print r1.read()" ? how can I get the XML ?

Comment: ok i got it now. just needed to append the parameters 'params' to the requested link as follwing: httpCon.request('GET', "/en/ppodnapisi/search?"+params)

Answer (score 3):

You accidentally included the protocol prefix in the `domain` argument to [HTTPConnection](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection). You want:

```
httpCon = HTTPConnection("www.podnapisi.net", 80)
```

Generally, This error indicates there was a problem resolving the domain name to an IP address. In  It might be just intermittent. If the problem persists, check the DNS configuration on your system.

For example, you can [set it to use Google's public DNS server](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html). For more information about how to configure your DNS server on Microsoft Windows, refer to [Microsoft's knowledge database](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-TCP-IP-settings).